# Online bank statement for a UK visit visa

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm applying for a UK visit visa. I have an account in a UK bank. Should this bank statement be stamped by the bank? And is it accepted as an online paper? Because it takes time to deliver to my country.

Comment: `I have an account in a UK bank` What is the purpose of having an UK bank account if you don't live in UK ? Don't assume just because you show an UK bank account your application will be seen in **+ve** light. It will complicate things as they might start asking why do you have a UK bank account to support your application.

Comment: I used to study at UK last year and my bank account still working. That’s why I want to show that I have a UK bank statement. In this part, do you think it’s a positive point? And I return to my first question, the bank statement might be online copy?

Comment: @Moha Online banking is extremely common in the UK and I’ve been assured by my own bank that statements (not transaction lists) downloaded from its website are legally acceptable, however I’ve seen comments on this site indicating that paper statements should be provided. The UK supporting documents guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf states ‘bank statements’, it is silent on what type.

Comment: @traveller thank you for your answer. I did my master from one of UK universities last year and I still have my UK bank account. I have a work here in my country and I transfer my money every year to my UK account. The question is: how could I explain that in my visa application? (I’m applying for a visitor visa to attend a conference)

Comment: @Moha You’ll need to provide evidence of the source of funds (your payslip) and bank statements from your home country or other evidence of the transfer source to tie up with the credit entries into your U.K. account. There is space at the end of the online application to provide a brief explanation if it’s not self-explanatory from your financial documents

Answer (score 2):

> Should this bank statement be stamped by the bank?

The UK supporting documents guide states:

> All documents must be originals and not photocopies.

This applies to your bank statements as well and the best option is to provide the originals and not the downloaded version to be absolutely safe. Having said that, I have not seen an application being rejected citing the reason: "Online bank statements are not accepted" and I know a lot of people who have supplied the printed version of bank statements with the visa application.

The important thing to note is that you have good savings and you should be able to provide the evidence of the source of funds.